# Toggle next section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a block of HTML:

```
<form>
    <section>
        <div class="row normalTopPadding personalInfomation">
            <!--Loads of HTML and Stuff-->
            <a id="myButton" class="reg-next-button btn btn-default">Next</a>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <div class="row normalTopPadding employerInfomation">
            <!--Loads of HTML and Stuff-->
            <a id="myButton" class="reg-next-button btn btn-default">Next</a>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <div class="row normalTopPadding accountInfomation">
            <!--Loads of HTML and Stuff-->
            <a id="myButton" class="reg-next-button btn btn-default">Next</a>
        </div>
    </section>
</form>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is for every time a button is clicked to hide the panel that the button has been clicked from and display the next panel down, so..

```
<script>
$('.personalInfomation .reg-next-button, .employerInformation .reg-next-button', .accountInformation .reg-next-button').click(function (e) {
    // Get the section that this button lives in
    var form = $(this).closest("section");

    //validation and other functions commented out for ease of reading

    // Hide this section...
    section.toggle();
    // And show the next section
    section.next().toggle();

});
</script>
```

Although this hides the section that the button has been clicked from it doesn't display the next one down.

Could someone point out my mistake?

Thanks,
C

Comment: You can't have more than one element with the same id.

Comment: I thing something is wrong, try to change

`var form = $(this).closest("section");`  to `var section = $(this).closest("section");`

Comment: And you last section has also a `next` button... that should....

Comment: Changing var form = $(this).closest("section"); to var section = $(this).closest("section"); Doesn't hide the current section (or display the next). Duly noted about the duplicate ID's (I was copy and pasting for ease).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check if next section is available or not and then hide current section.

NOTE: there is extra single quote in your jquery selector, which i have removed. Also, you have declared variable `form` but used `section`, so rename form to section

```
$('.personalInfomation .reg-next-button, .employerInformation .reg-next-button, .accountInformation .reg-next-button').click(function (e) {
    // Get the section that this button lives in
    var section = $(this).closest("section");

    //validation and other functions commented out for ease of reading

    // Hide this section...
    var $next = section.next();
    if($next.length>0) {  // check condition first and then hide current section and show next
       section.toggle();
      // And show the next section
      $next.toggle();
   }
});
```

Instead of putting each section in button click handler you can generalise it and improve your code so that when you add new section you don't need to change your script.

**NOTE** - do not use same id for multiple html elements as you have used it for button

```js
$(function(){
$('section .row.normalTopPadding .reg-next-button').on('click', function (e) {
  var section = $(this).closest("section");
  var $next = section.next();
  if($next.length>0) {  // check condition first and then hide current section and show next
      section.addClass('hide');
      $next.removeClass('hide');
   }
});
});
```

```css
.hide {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <section>
        <div class="row normalTopPadding personalInfomation">
            <!--Loads of HTML and Stuff-->
            This is SECTION 1
            <a id="myButton" class="reg-next-button btn btn-default">Next</a>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="hide">
        <div class="row normalTopPadding employerInfomation">
            <!--Loads of HTML and Stuff-->
            This is SECTION 2
            <a id="myButton" class="reg-next-button btn btn-default">Next</a>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="hide">
        <div class="row normalTopPadding accountInfomation">
            <!--Loads of HTML and Stuff-->
            This is SECTION 3
            <a id="myButton" class="reg-next-button btn btn-default">Next</a>
        </div>
    </section>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but this still but it's not finding the next section for displaying and as such not hiding the section that it's currently in

Comment: I missed that you have defined `form` variable and using `section` variable. I have corrected it in my answer. Also, provided other clean solution with css class `hide`

Answer (score 0):

You may try to hide all the sections first, and then on click of `a`, find the next `.row` to be shown.

See the demo below:

```js
$('.row').not(':first').css('display', 'none');

$('.row > a').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('.row').toggle();
  $(this).parents('section').next('section').find('.row').toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <section>
    <div class="row normalTopPadding personalInfomation">
      <!--Loads of HTML and Stuff-->
      <a id="myButton" class="reg-next-button btn btn-default">Next 1</a>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="row normalTopPadding employerInfomation">
      <!--Loads of HTML and Stuff-->
      <a id="myButton" class="reg-next-button btn btn-default">Next 2</a>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="row normalTopPadding accountInfomation">
      <!--Loads of HTML and Stuff-->
      <a id="myButton" class="reg-next-button btn btn-default">Next 3</a>
    </div>
  </section>
</form>
```